# Can $ x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \Big{(}- \gamma - \psi \big{(}1-\frac{x}{k} \big{)} \Big{)} $ be simplified?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, generating-functions, closed-form-expressions

I'm interested in sums of the form $$f_{p} (x) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \zeta(k)^{p} x^{k} .$$

For $p=1$, the following result is known: $$f_{1} (x) = -x \big{(}\psi(1-x) + \gamma \big{)} .$$

(That is, when $|x| < 1$.)

For $p = 2$, user Antonio DJC seems to have made [progress](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817222/generating-function-of-the-squared-riemann-zeta-function) towards finding the closed form of the sum:

$$f_{2}(x) = x  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \Big{(}- \gamma - \psi \big{(}1-\frac{x}{k} \big{)} \Big{)} .$$

Here, $\psi(\cdot)$ is the Digamma function.

Considering there are quite a few identities known with regards to (sums of) values of the digamma function -- see for instance [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406338.pdf) article and Gauss's digamma theorem -- I wonder whether it is possible to simplify $f_{2} (\cdot)$.

P.S. as a bonus question, I am curious about research on the general case $f_{p} (\cdot)$, with $p \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} $. Is there any literature on this generating function?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik the series does converge. One needs to consider the addition of the $\gamma$-constant in each term.

Comment: $f_{p+1}(x)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint\limits_{C}f(xz)f(\frac{1}{z})dz$ where $C$ is the unit circle. With this , using residue theorem ($\psi(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$\ $-\mathbb N$ ) we can very easily find $f_2(x)=-x\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (\gamma+\psi(1-\frac{x}{k}))$. This can be used to find similar summation forms of $f_3(x), f_4(x)$... For example, $f_3(x)$ will be something like $$-x\sum_{m,n≥1} \frac{1}{mn}(\gamma+\psi(1-\frac{x}{mn}))$$.

Comment: In general, $f_p(x)=$$$-x\sum_{k_1,k_2,...,k_{p-1} ≥1} \frac{1}{(\prod_{i=1}^{p-1} k_i)}(\gamma+\psi\left(1-\frac{x}{\prod_{i=1}^{p-1} k_i}\right))$$.